# TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'float' and 'function'

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to create a very simple virus-cure simulation. I created two files (infection.py and medicine.py), one simulating a virus and one simulating a very simplified cure. The first program works perfectly fine on its own. It is returning a list containing the amount of viruses for each time unit. The second program has the first program imported and is supossed to create some kind of cure. I mostly use predefined functions from program 1, and I redefined `simulate()`.

To understand this program: 'The Cure' starts after `timestep = 100`, this is after the virus has been diagnosed. The virus can only reproduce if it is resistant to the cure, in other words, if the virus contains 'AAA'. A virus can die, reproduce and mutate. A mutation can sometimes result in resistancy.

Everything should be working (in theory?), however I get the same error message over and over again when running program 2: `TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'float' and 'function'`. I know what it means, but it says the error comes from a function predefined in program 1. But program 1 has no difficulty running this function whatsoever. I tried storing the value of `random.random()` and then using it, but this did not work. This is my code:

PROGRAM 1

```
import random

def generateVirus(length):
    return ''.join([random.choice(['A', 'G', 'T', 'C']) for i in range(length)])

def mutate(virus):
    rand = random.randint(0, len(virus)-1)
    return virus[:rand] + random.choice([i for i in 'AGTC' if i != virus[rand]]) + virus[rand+1:]

def kill(viruses, mortalityProb):
    return [survivors for survivors in viruses if random.random() > mortalityProb]

def reproduce(viruses, mutationProb, reproductionProb):
    nextgen = []
    for i in viruses:
        nextgen.append(i)
        if random.random() < reproductionProb:
            if random.random() < mutationProb:
                nextgen.append(mutate(i))
            else:
                nextgen.append(i)
    return nextgen

def reproductionProbability(viruses, maxReproductionProb, maxPopulation):
    return (1 - (len(viruses) / maxPopulation)) * maxReproductionProb

def simulate(viruses, mortalityProb, mutationProb, maxReproductionProb, 
    maxPopulation, timesteps = 500):
    pop_size = []
    while timesteps > -1:
        survivors = kill(viruses, mortalityProb)
        reproductionProb = reproductionProbability(survivors, maxReproductionProb, maxPopulation)
        viruses = reproduce(survivors, mutationProb, reproductionProb)
        pop_size.append(len(viruses))
        timesteps -= 1
    return pop_size

print(simulate(['GCTCC', 'CCGG', 'AACCGG', 'CCCTATAGG'], 0.05, 0.1, 0.07, 1000))
```

PROGRAM 2

```
import infection

def isResistent(virus):
    if virus.find('AAA') > -1:
        return True
    else:
        return False

def simulate(viruses, mortalityProb, mutationProb, maxReproductionProb, maxPopulation, timesteps = 500):
    activation_cure = 400
    while timesteps > -1:
        survivors = infection.kill(viruses, mortalityProb)
        for virus in viruses:
            if timesteps < activation_cure and isResistent(virus):
                reproductionProb = infection.reproductionProbability
                infection.reproduce(viruses, mutationProb, reproductionProb)
        timesteps -= 1
    return len(viruses)

def experiment(numberOfPatients):
    cured = 0
    viruses = []
    for i in range(10):
        viruses.append(infection.generateVirus(16))
    for i in range(numberOfPatients):
        remaining_virus = simulate(viruses, 0.05, 0.1, 0.07, 1000)
        if remaining_virus[len(remaining_virus)-1] == 0:
            cured += 1
    return cured

print(experiment(5))
```

COMPLETE ERROR MESSAGE

```
File "C:\something\workspace\infection.py", line 17, in reproduce
if random.random() < reproductionProb:
TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'float' and 'function'
```

Comment: `infection.reproductionProbability` is a function that you are passing as a parameter. Did you mean to call the function and pass the result instead?

Comment: `reproductionProb = infection.reproductionProbability` in PROGRAM 2 is the line where a function is assigned to what probably should be a probability value.

Comment: Try capturing the random float value before the if condition in a variable
`rand1=random.random()
if random.random() < reproductionProb:`

Comment: You're right! Thank you both for helping me out! @PeterWood

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error message is clear: This line (line 17) is the problem:

```
 if random.random() < reproductionProb
```

`random.random()` is a float and `reproductionProb` a function handle. You cannot compare a float with a function.

```
reproductionProb = infection.reproductionProbability
```

is the call where you are passing a function handle instead of a float.

Also you need to make sure to encapsulate your main function as:

```
if __name__=='__main__':
```

If you import your file this prevents the main function of the imported file being called.

Comment: You're totally right. I changed that line of code into `reproductionProb = infection.reproductionProbability(survivors, maxReproductionProb, maxPopulation)` and it's working now! Thanks for the help!